# Enter key listener for Google keyboard is not working

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I want to add a functionality on click of "enter" key of Google's keyboard without vanquishing the default newline characteristic. I have used OnKeyListener but it is not  working.

```
      EditText edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.user_query);
      edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
      public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
          if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode ==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)) {
          //here  i want to print numbers with next line in edit text
          return true;
    }
    return false;
    }
});
```

The same code is working with other keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html)

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a hardware key
>   event is dispatched to this view. The callback will be invoked before
>   the key event is given to the view. This is only useful for hardware
>   keyboards; a software input method has no obligation to trigger this
>   listener.

And the most safe bet would be to use addTextChangedListener in your case like below

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {          
     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {                                   
         //here is your code       
    }                       
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }                       
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
    }
});
```