# Android Enter Key Listener is not work

Tags: android, keyboard, enter

I had tried almost every method I searched.But for some keyboard like TouchPal，Swype these methods didn't work.

1. imeOptions

   `<EditText android:imeOptions="actionSend"/>`
2. setOnKeyListener
3. dispatchKeyEvent
4. onEditorAction

---

And I also find this [Enter key listener for Google keyboard is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39375467/enter-key-listener-for-google-keyboard-is-not-working/39375538#39375538)

So I use this , it really worked.

```
        if (isPressEnterSendMsg) {
                if (s == null)
                    return;
                String str = s.toString().substring(start, start + count);
                if (str.equals("\n")) {
                    chatEditContent.setText(s.toString().replaceFirst("\n", ""));
                    chatSendButton.performClick();
                    return;
                }
            }
```

With the app testing,I found it's ok when I input normal message include small expression,when include SpannableString I press enter , the s in method onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) will be "".

Then I found I cannot setText in onTextChanged method,I searched agin,I can removeTextChangedListener in onTextChanged and then addTextChangedListener,But didn't work...

So I want to ask if there any other solution I can do ?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try using `android:imeOptions="actionGo"` ?

Comment: I debug and find when I use TouchPal and Swype I event cannot catch the enter key and event.

Comment: This link should help you handle the Enter key event. [Handle Enter event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489852/android-handle-enter-in-an-edittext)

Comment: Thank you so much ,But it didn't work :(

Comment: Hi,I finally resolved by this link [Multiline EditText with Done SoftInput Action Label on 2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014219/multiline-edittext-with-done-softinput-action-label-on-2-3)